# double to char* conversion. Weird results from dtostrf

Tags: data-type

**Here’s the code:**

```
void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
    delay(300);

    double lat = 1111.11;
    double lon = 4444.44;

    const byte len{10};

    char sLat[len];
    char sLon[len];

    dtostrf(lat, len, 2, sLat);
    Serial.println(sLat);

    Serial.println("---");

    dtostrf(lon, len, 2, sLon);
    Serial.println(sLon);
    Serial.println(sLat); // <-- prints nothing!

    Serial.println("---");

    dtostrf(lat, len, 2, sLat);
    Serial.println(sLat);
    Serial.println(sLon); // <-- prints nothing!
}

void loop()
{
}
```

**Here’s the output:**

```
   1111.11
---
   4444.44

---
   1111.11
   4444.44   1111.11
```

As you see. Every next call for `dtostrf` ruins the previous results, in a weird way.

What’s the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `len` is the text array size, you need space there for the terminating '\0'.
So the second paramater to `dtostrf` has to be smaller than `len`.

Comment: Yeah, of course, your're right! Thanks a lot! I fixed declaration: `char sLat[len+1]`